# How to put buttons below scrollview and always show button without being overlapped by scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My layout is like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchKey"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="xx" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_results"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_font_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lastCharacterButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lastChar_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextCharacterButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nextChar_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, when there are little or no text, the buttons are pulled up, when there are too many text in search_results TextView, the buttons won't show up because scrollview takes the space all the way to the bottom. Any suggestion to always keep the buttons at the bottom and always visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to set the ScrollView's height to 0dp.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_results"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_font_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

You have to do this because the weight param is going to control the size of the view depending on how much space is available. If you set it to wrap content, it will take how much space it needs to wrap everything within.

Then you need to remove your LinearLayout's weight param:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:id="@+id/LL1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lastCharacterButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last_Char" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextCharacterButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="next_char" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

And the reason for doing that is just the opposite of the previous explanation: in this case the wrap content is going to take the space necessary to always display the buttons within.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code I put together for you. You basically need to take out the linear layout you have wrapping you xml layout and use a relative layout instead. Once you do that you can add ids to the linear layout with the buttons and then have the edit text align to the parent top. Then you can put the scrollview below the edittext and then put the scrollview above to the linear layout containing the buttons. This should work!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.thegamefan93.loginregister.LoginActivity">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchKey"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="xx" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/searchKey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/LL1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/search_results"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/LL1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/lastCharacterButton"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Last_Char" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nextCharacterButton"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="next_char" />

            </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchKey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="xx" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchKey"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_results"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_font_size" />
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lastCharacterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lastChar_btn" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextCharacterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/nextChar_btn" />

                </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```